# Android, switch/case on View with programmatically generated views

Tags: android, view, switch-statement

Normally, when I switch/case my views onClick, I have no problems because they were defined in the XML and have ID's so I use:

```
switch(v.getID())
{
case(R.id.someButton):
{
  // do something
}
default: // bla
}
```

However, I am now defining my views programatically and so they don't have a static ID.

How should I now switch on these views? if I tried getID() on the views it's not allowed because it isn't static.

Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:
You should create  [ids.xml](https://developer.android.com/samples/BatchStepSensor/res/values/ids.html) file and refer it in your code while creating view programmatically.

Comment: Why would anybody want to abuse the strings.xml when they already have ids.xml whose sole purpose is to address this usecase

Comment: @Kalinga Updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do View.setId() when you create your views.

Answer (score 0):

Then, don't use the switch statement (IMO, it looks bad, just IMO). So, if you are generating views programmatically, set a click listener programmatically too:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        // execute specific behavior
    }
});
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this. I have 20 of these Views that I want to call the same method on. Is there an easier solution? I tried v.doStuff() but "doStuff" is only recognised for a certain (custom) View.

Comment: No need really, I instantiate 13 buttons, then I need to do something when one of them is pressed. Each button calls the same method but with different parameters. Just looking for a way to tidy it up instead of creating a new onClick for each button.